# What is the value of DbParameter.Size if DbParameter.DbType is Binary?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working with Visual Studio 2010, .Net Framework 4 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a table and one of its column's data type is `timestamp`. I am trying to setup a `DbParameter` for this column. Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings I can see that the `DbParameter.DbType` for this column should be `Binary`. But what should be the value of `DbParameter.Size` for this column?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to read you got stuck in the past. I'll send Doc Brown to get you back to 2019. I mean, seriously, Don't you think it's high time to upgrade your VS and SQL Server?

To answer your question, In SQL Server, `Timestamp` is a [synonym](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-synonyms-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to [`RowVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).
From documentation:

> [rowversion] Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary numbers within a database. rowversion is generally used as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows. **The storage size is 8 bytes.** The rowversion data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time.

(emphasis mine)

Also, from the same documentation page:

> **Note**
>
> The timestamp syntax is deprecated. This feature is in maintenance mode and may be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

BTW, `RowVersion` is automatically generated - so unless your parameter is an `out` parameter, I see no reason to use it in a parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Only stuck in the past with a particular client of our company. For most other clients we are working with Visual Studio 2019 and SQL Server 2016.

Comment: `Timestamp` type parameter is an `out` parameter in my case so thats why I needed to know its size.